# What happens to a rectangle triangle if I divide per 2 a side length?

Tags: triangles, triangle-inequality

Ok so I have a triangle ABC:

- Rectangle in the angle A
- BC = 49

And let's say:

- AB = y
- AC = x

That's the only values I have.
Now, let's say I divide per 2 the AC value, what happens to the hypotenuse? And what is its new value?

Hope you can understand me, ask me if you need another information or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If by a rectangle you mean a right angle, then initially we have $$x^2+y^2=49^2 $$

If $AC$ is halved, then the new hypotenuse length becomes $$\sqrt{\left(\frac x2\right)^2 + y^2 } =\sqrt{ x^2 +y^2 +\frac{x^2}{4} -x^2 }=\sqrt{49^2 -\frac 34 x^2} $$

You’ll need the value of one of $x$ or $y$ to deduce the exact value.